# Screet WP Chat - current domain is not authorized for OAuth operations

Tags: firebase, chat, firebase-authentication

I am currently using this plugin for my wordpress page: https://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-live-chat-plugin/395287

It works on one of my site and randomly stopped on another. After a bit of troubleshooting, I found this error by looking on the console in Chrome:

*"The current domain is not authorized for OAuth operations. This will prevent signInWithPopup, signInWithRedirect, linkWithPopup and linkWithRedirect from working. Add your domain (XXXX) to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab."*

However, the issue with this is that I already did this. And I tried deleting the project and making a new one but always the same error even though the OAuth is there with the domain in question.

I'm so confused on why it's saying it's not authorized when I can physically see it listed on the OAuth redirect domains list.

All my searching didn't yield any result except to add it to the OAuth Domain list, but again, it's already there and still not working. O.o? I'm new to firebase and had it working at one point but it stopped working at one point or another. I'm not sure when.

Other (maybe) important info:

- site was hacked at one point so we deleted everything and did everything again fresh.
- when I installed the plugin, it worked just fine with the exception of some colors not showing up.
- I think it may have stopped with the new updates for the plugin itself, but I can't be sure especially with the message above.

Comment: Can you check the browser network console? Do you see any 400 errors? Can you check the request to getProjectConfig endpoint? That holds the key to why this may be happening.

Comment: I got an error 403. JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
[GOOGLE URL HERE]  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
schat.frontend.ui.js?ver=2.2.8:114 Q
(anonymous) @ schat.frontend.ui.js?ver=2.2.8:114
[GOOGLE URL HERE] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

Comment: I'm not sure what any of that means....but where do I "check the request to getProjectConfig endpoint"?

Comment: in the network log, there should be a get request to a url ending with getProjectConfig?key=****. Can you see that at all?

Comment: yes, I can see that. I'm not sure what I am looking at though. Can you PM me? i'm new to this site and I'm not sure if there even is a PM function... if not, email would work.